# Fraction operators

Tags: c++, string, class, operator-keyword

i need to write a program to calculate fractions, here is my header file:

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Fraction {

    private:
        int *numer;
        int *denom;
        int gcd(int, int);
    public:
        void reduce();
        int getNum();
        int getDen();
        Fraction();
        Fraction(int numerator);
        Fraction(int num, int den);
        Fraction(string s);  // take string parameter of the form of "numerator/defnominator
        Fraction(Fraction &other);  // copy constructor
        Fraction & operator=(Fraction & rhs);
        ~Fraction();
        // overloading arithematic operation
        Fraction & operator+ (Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator- (Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator* (Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator/ (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator > (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator >= (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator == (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator < (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator <= (Fraction & rhs);
        bool operator!=(Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator++();
        Fraction & operator++(int);
        Fraction & operator--();
        Fraction & operator--(int);

        Fraction & operator+=(Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator-=(Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator*=(Fraction & rhs);
        Fraction & operator/=(Fraction & rhs);

        // Exponentiation 
        Fraction & operator^(int n);

        bool isZero();
        bool isProper();  // a fracton is proper if abs(numerator) < (denominator)
        bool isNegative();
        bool isPositive();

        operator string();
        operator double();

        string toString();
        string toProperString();   // properString format of 15/4   is  3 3/4

        friend ostream & operator <<  (ostream & out, Fraction & rhs);
        friend istream & operator >> (istream & in, Fraction &rhs);
};

#endif
```

for the Fraction.cpp file:

I have the function that converts the faction format to string, here's what i have, but not sure if it is correct.
Here is what i got now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include<iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Fraction.h"
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

Fraction::Fraction()
{
    numer = new int(0);
    denom = new int(1);
    //cout<<"construtor"<<endl;
}
int Fraction::getNum()
{
    return *numer;

}
int Fraction::getDen()
{
    return *denom;
}
int Fraction::gcd(int n, int d)      //moving sign to numerator
{
    //assert((n > 0 && d > 0));         //ensuring numerator and demominator have no common divisors 
    //while (n != d)                    // return the greatest common divisor 
    //{
    //  if (n < d)
    //      d = d - n;
    //  else
    //      n = n - d;
    //}
    //return n;
    if(n<0)
        n=-n;
    if(d<0)
        d=-d;
    if(n<d)
        return gcd(d,n);
    if(d==0)
        return n;
    return gcd(d,n%d);

}
Fraction::Fraction(int numerator)
{
    numer = new int(numerator);
    denom= new int (1);
    //printf("Fraction::Fraction(int numerator) \n");
}

Fraction::Fraction(int num, int den)
{
    assert (den != 0);

    numer = new int(num);
    denom = new int(den);
    reduce();

    //cout<<"reduce function"<<endl;
}
void Fraction::reduce()
{
    int sign = 1;
    if (*numer < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        *numer = -*numer;
    }
    if (*numer< 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        *denom = -*denom;
    }
    assert(*denom != 0);
    int d = 1;
    if (*numer>0)
    {
        d= gcd(*numer, *denom);
        *numer = sign*(*numer / d);
        *denom = *denom / d;
    }
}

Fraction::Fraction(string s)
{
    string delimiter = "/";
    string n = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
    string d=s.substr(s.find(delimiter)+1,s.length());

    numer = new int (atoi(n.c_str()));
    denom = new int(atoi(d.c_str()));   //every first time using pointer in constructor 
    cout << n << d << endl;
    //constructor 
}
Fraction::Fraction(Fraction &other)
{
    numer = new int( other.getNum());     
    denom = new int(other.getDen());
    //cout<<"copy construtor"<<endl;
}

Fraction::~Fraction()
{
    delete numer;
    numer = 0;           //if (numer) if(denom) 
    delete denom;
    denom = 0;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator=(Fraction & rhs)
{  
    if (this != &rhs)
    {                          //do i need delete pointer here? 
        *numer = rhs.getNum();
        *denom = rhs.getDen();
    }
    else
        return *this;
}
Fraction & Fraction::operator+ (Fraction & rhs)
{
    Fraction *result = new Fraction(this->getNum()*rhs.getDen() + this->getDen()*rhs.getNum(), this->getDen()*rhs.getDen());
    result->reduce();
    return *result;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator- (Fraction & rhs)
{
    Fraction *result=new Fraction((this->getNum()*rhs.getDen() - this->getDen()*rhs.getNum(), this->getDen()*rhs.getDen()));
    result->reduce();
    return *result;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator*(Fraction & rhs)
{
    Fraction *result=new Fraction((this->getNum()*rhs.getNum(), this->getDen()*rhs.getDen()));
    result->reduce();
    return *result;

}

Fraction & Fraction::operator/(Fraction & rhs)
{
    Fraction *result=new Fraction((this->getNum()*rhs.getDen(), this->getDen()*rhs.getNum()));
    result->reduce();
    return *result;
}

bool Fraction::operator > (Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (((float)getNum() / getDen())>((float)rhs.getDen() / rhs.getNum()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::operator >= (Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (((float)getNum() / getDen()) >= ((float)rhs.getDen() / rhs.getNum()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::operator == (Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (getNum()*rhs.getDen() == getDen()*rhs.getNum())
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
bool Fraction::operator < (Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (((float)getNum() / getDen())<((float)rhs.getDen() / rhs.getNum()))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool Fraction::operator <= (Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (((float)getNum() / getDen()) <= ((float)rhs.getDen() / rhs.getNum()))
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::operator!=(Fraction & rhs)
{
    if (getNum()*rhs.getDen() == getDen()*rhs.getNum())
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

Fraction & Fraction::operator++()  //pre fix 
{
    *numer += *denom;
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator++(int inInt)  //post fix
{

    Fraction *temp = new Fraction (*this);
    *numer += *denom;
    reduce();
    return *temp;

}

Fraction & Fraction::operator--()
{
    *numer -= *denom;
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator--(int)
{
    Fraction *temp = new Fraction(*this);
    *numer -= *denom;
    reduce();
    return *temp;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator+=(Fraction & rhs)
{
    *numer = (*numer)*rhs.getDen() + (*denom)*rhs.getNum();
    *denom = (*denom)*rhs.getDen();
    reduce();
    return *this;

}
Fraction & Fraction::operator-=(Fraction & rhs)
{
    *numer = (*numer)*rhs.getDen() - (*denom)*rhs.getNum();
    *denom = (*denom)*rhs.getDen();
    reduce();
    return *this;
}
Fraction & Fraction::operator*=(Fraction & rhs)
{
    *numer=(*numer)*rhs.getNum();
    *denom=(*denom)*rhs.getDen();
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

Fraction & Fraction::operator/=(Fraction & rhs)
{
    *numer=(*numer)*rhs.getDen();
    *denom=(*denom)*rhs.getNum();
    reduce();
    return *this;

}

Fraction & Fraction::operator^(int n)
{
    *numer = (double)pow((float)*numer, n);

    *denom = (double)pow((float)*denom, n);
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

bool Fraction::isZero()
{
    return (*numer) == 0;
}

bool Fraction::isProper()
{
    if (abs(*numer)<abs(*denom))
        return true;
    else 
        return false; 
}

bool Fraction::isNegative()
{
    if (*numer<0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool Fraction::isPositive()
{
    if (*numer>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

Fraction::operator string()
{
    return this->toString();
}
Fraction::operator double()
{
    return ((double)(*numer) / (*denom));
}

string Fraction::toString()
{
    char num[100], deom[100];
    char *s = new char[50];
    itoa(*numer, num, 10);
    itoa(*denom, deom, 10);

    char * delimiter = new char[2];
    delimiter[0] = '\/';
    delimiter[1] = '\0';   //stops copying delimiter 

    strcpy(s, num);
    strcat(s, delimiter);
    //  strcat(s,'\0');
    strcat(s, deom);
    //  strcat(s,'\0');

    return s;

}
string Fraction::toProperString()
{
    int a = *(this->numer) / *(this->denom);
    int num = *(this->numer) % *(this->denom);
    ostringstream ostr;
    ostr <<a << " " << num << "/" << *(this->denom);
    return ostr.str();

}

ostream & operator <<  (ostream & out, Fraction & rhs)
{
    if(rhs.getDen()!=1)
    {
        out << rhs.getNum() << "/" << rhs.getDen();
    }
    else
        cout<<rhs.getNum();
    return out;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & in, Fraction &rhs)
{
    int n, d;
    in >> n;
    char c;
    in >> c;
    if (c == '/')
        in >> d;
    else
    {
        in.putback(c);
        d = 1;
    }
    rhs = Fraction(n, d);
    return in; 
}
```

And here's the main program

```
#include "Fraction.h"

void main()
{
    Fraction a1;
    Fraction a(1,2);
    Fraction b(4,5);
    Fraction c(6,8);
    Fraction d(b);
    Fraction g(-4,8);
    Fraction g1(4,-10);
    Fraction z(7,5);

    cout << a1 << endl;
    cout << a  << endl;
    cout << b  << endl;
    cout << c  << endl;
    cout << d  << endl;
    cout << g  << endl;
    cout << g1 << endl;

    string s  = "3/4";
    string s1 = "2/-3";
    Fraction b1(s);
    Fraction b2(s1);

    cout << b1 << endl;
    cout << b2 << endl;

    a1 = b + c; cout << a1 << endl;
    a1 = b-c  ; cout << a1 << endl;
    a1 = b*c  ; cout << a1 << endl;
    a1 = b / c; cout << a1 << endl;

    b += a; cout << b << endl; 
    b -= a; cout << b << endl; 
    b /= a; cout << b << endl; 
    b++   ; cout << b << endl; 
    ++b   ; cout << b << endl; 
    b--   ; cout << b << endl; 
    --b   ; cout << b << endl; 
    b /= a; cout << b << endl; 
    b *a  ; cout << b << endl; 
    b^2   ; cout << b << endl; 

    cout << a.toString()       << endl;
    cout << z.toProperString() << endl;

    Fraction f1(-4,5);
    Fraction f2(0,1);
    cout << "is f1 negative?"             << f1.isNegative() << endl;
    cout << "is f2 zero?"                 << f2.isZero()     << endl;
    cout << "is f1 a proper fraction?"    << f1.isProper()   << endl;
    cout << "is f1 a positive fraction? " << f1.isPositive() << endl;

    a = Fraction(9, 8);
    b = Fraction(7, 8);

    if (a < b)
        cout << "a is smaller than b"   << endl;
    else
        cout << " a is larger than b"   << endl;

    if(a==b)
        cout << "a is equal to b"       << endl;
    else
        cout << "a does not equal to b" << endl;
}
```

Since no one was willing to help me, so I post all the codes here for everyone. 
I took me a while to finish this project with the help of my TA.

Comment: Is the header file part of the asignment or did you write it? Why pointers for numer and denom?

Comment: it's part of the assignment. No one likes pointers.

Comment: Yes i do :) Can you maybe show the full C part?

Comment: yea, but the main function is incomplete tho.

Comment: @deviantfan: What do you mean by "full C part"? The code is C++, not C.

Comment: `string` and `double` operators? I'm confused... I think there's maybe been an error copying something down? Those functions don't make any sense to me.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sorry, i meant C++.

Comment: @aardvarkk those are conversion operators, used to convert to the given types automatically.

Comment: Can you guys help me out here? I don't know what to do with these conversion operators.

Comment: @MarkRansom Crazy -- I don't think I've encountered those before. Learn something new every day, thanks!

Comment: @user3285116 I'd just implement one in terms of the other, e.g. `Fraction::operator string() { return toString(); }`

Comment: `operator^` is a bad choice for exponentiation, since it has an unexpected precendence. Implicit conversion functions (especially `operator double`, which loses precision) are generally a bad idea, since they can happen when you don't expect them. And the use of pointers rather than integer members is just insane. I hope this is presented as an example of how *not* to design a class; otherwise, you're being taught some very bad habits.

Comment: @Mike Seymour whats the better way to do that? And i will send your quote to my professor, lol

Comment: Also, `operator+` and the like must return a value, not a reference. Returning a reference to a local variable (which has been destroyed by the time the function has returned) isn't just a bad idea; it's categorically wrong. The better way to do this is to drop your course and invest in a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242) instead.

Comment: @MikeSeymour oh well,that's the option i don't have. But can you teach me how to do it the right way? Just for the conversion functions

Comment: Um, your post doesn't actually ask a question. It just is a wall of code. Please put a question in the post.

Comment: @Kunlin If you "don't have the option to learn the basics correctly", why should we spend time teaching you?

Comment: since no one was willing or able to help me, so I post all the codes here for everyone. I took me a while to finish this project with the help of my TA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In various spots you're using

   ```
   Fraction *result=new Fraction((this->getNum()*rhs.getDen() - this->getDen()*rhs.getNum(), this->getDen()*rhs.getDen()));
   ```

   This needs to be

   ```
   Fraction *result=new Fraction(this->getNum()*rhs.getDen() - this->getDen()*rhs.getNum(), this->getDen()*rhs.getDen());
   ```

   or you'll actually be passing only `this->getDen()*rhs.getDen()` ([How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)). Also **see bullet 3.**
2. `Fraction & Fraction::operator=(Fraction & rhs)` fails to return a value in all cases (drop the `else`)
3. THIS ISN'T JAVA. Don't do `new int(1)`. Just: `int(1)`. Saves you the head-ache of memory management ([What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three))
4. Don't do `using namespace std;`. Certainly not in header files ([Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). Also **see bullet 19.**
5. Prefer the C++11 headers (e.g. `<cstdlib>`) over the C library headers 
   (`<stdlib.h>`)
6. Your `toString` method uses non-standard `itoa`. Also, it leaks several char buffers on each invocation... Try c++ style:

   ```
   string Fraction::toString()
   {
       return std::to_string(*numer) + '/' + std::to_string(*denom);
   }
   ```

   See? A single line, no more leaks. No more NUL-terminating temporaries. No more `strcat` nonsense. Just business logic. (Still need to fix the other things mentioned in earlier bullets, of course)
7. Oh, and make members `const` when possible

   ```
   string Fraction::toString() const
   ```
8. It needs to be `int main()`, not `void`. At least for standard-conforming/portable code.
9. Copy constructors must take `const&` arguments.

   ```
   Fraction(Fraction const& other);  // copy constructor
   ```

   Same for the copy-assignment operator.

   The following line should **not** have compiled on a standards-conforming compiler:

   ```
   rhs = Fraction(n, d);
   ```

   Reason is, the temporary (rhs) cannot (legally) bind to a non-const reference parameter. **Note** this again makes it important that you mark `getNum()` and `getDen()` as `const`, or you won't be able to call them on the argument
10. Returning references from operators that *by convention* have const semantics, violates Principle Of Least Surprise and is hence considered harmful:

    - `Fraction& Fraction::operator+(Fraction&)` should return by value
    - `Fraction& Fraction::operator-(Fraction&)` should return by value
    - `Fraction& Fraction::operator*(Fraction&)` should return by value
    - `Fraction& Fraction::operator/(Fraction&)` should return by value
    - postfix `Fraction& Fraction::operator++(int)` should return `Fraction`
    - postfix `Fraction& Fraction::operator--(int)` should return `Fraction`

    It's very easy to use the results of these operators and get something wholly unexpected. Given `const`-correctness, the problem is lessened, but the operators are still less useful than they could be.
11. Don't mix `double` and `float` unless you know what you're doing (hint: you don't: [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples/2100502#2100502))

    > ***time passes***...
    > *Okay, I've cleaned up a bit more. All uses of `new` were completely misguided (sorry). A **lot** of code could be simplified by reuse.*
12. don't `if (cond) return true; else return false;`. Instead just `return cond;`
13. your constructor already does `reduce()`. So, make your operators just rely on that instead of doing redundant reductions:

    ```
     Fraction Fraction::operator*(Fraction const& rhs) const {
         return Fraction(numer*rhs.numer, denom*rhs.denom);
     }

     Fraction& Fraction::operator*=(Fraction const& rhs) {
         return *this = (*this * rhs);
     }
    ```
14. the destructor is now redundant (no more pointers!)
15. the constructors have been summarized into three:

    ```
     Fraction(int num = 0, int den = 1);
     Fraction(std::string const& s);  // take string parameter of the form of "numerator/defnominator
     Fraction(Fraction const& other);  // copy constructor
    ```
16. constructors use initializer lists:

    ```
     Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int den) : numer(numerator), denom(den)
     {
         assert(denom != 0);
         reduce();
     }
    ```
17. `gcd` could be static (and doesn't need to be a class member. Just make it file static in the implementation file)
18. some "test cases" and output are rather useless, e.g.

    ```
         b *a  ; cout << b << endl; 
         b^2u  ; cout << b << endl;
    ```

    doesn't print **anything** related to the expressions. I've updated them to be more useful:

    ```
         b *= a;     cout << "b *= a; // "     << b  << endl; 
         b ^= 2u;    cout << "b ^= 2; // "     << b  << endl;
    ```
19. you accidentally used `cout` instead of `out` in `operator<<`
20. don't do floating point equality, even in `operator>=`,`<=` (see above about `float` and `double`, **see bullet 11.**)

Without further ado, here's my version. **Disclaimer** I didn't check much of the logic. I just reviewed coding problems and style.

Output:

```
a1: 0
a : 1/2
b : 4/5
c : 3/4
d : 4/5
g : -1/2
g1: 2/-5
b1: 3/4
b2: 2/-3
a1 = b + c; // 31/20
a1 = b-c  ; // 1/20
a1 = b*c  ; // 3/5
a1 = b / c; // 16/15
b += a; // 13/10
b -= a; // 4/5
b /= a; // 8/5
b++   ; // 13/5
++b   ; // 18/5
b--   ; // 13/5
--b   ; // 8/5
b /= a; // 16/5
b *= a; // 8/5
b ^= 2; // 64/25
1/2
1 2/5
is f1 negative? true
is f2 zero? true
is f1 a proper fraction? true
is f1 a positive fraction? false
a is not smaller than b
a is not equal to b
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a252ab3fa62c4d7b)**

Note that the code compiles cleanly with all warnings enabled: `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Werror -Weffc++`

#### Code Listing

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>

class Fraction {

    private:
        int numer;
        int denom;
        // static int gcd(int, int);
    public:
        void reduce();
        int getNum() const;
        int getDen() const;
        Fraction(int num = 0, int den = 1);
        Fraction(std::string const& s);  // take string parameter of the form of "numerator/denominator
        Fraction(Fraction const& other);  // copy constructor
        Fraction& operator=(Fraction const& rhs);
        // overloading arithematic operation
        Fraction  operator+  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        Fraction  operator-  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        Fraction  operator*  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        Fraction  operator/  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator>  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator>= (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator== (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator<  (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator<= (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        bool      operator!= (Fraction const& rhs) const;
        Fraction& operator++ ();
        Fraction& operator-- ();
        Fraction  operator++ (int);
        Fraction  operator-- (int);

        Fraction& operator+=(Fraction const& rhs);
        Fraction& operator-=(Fraction const& rhs);
        Fraction& operator*=(Fraction const& rhs);
        Fraction& operator/=(Fraction const& rhs);

        // Exponentiation
        Fraction operator^(unsigned n) const;
        Fraction& operator^=(unsigned n);

        bool isZero()     const;
        bool isProper()   const; // a fracton is proper if abs(numerator) < (denominator)
        bool isNegative() const;
        bool isPositive() const;

        operator std::string() const;
        operator double() const;

        std::string toString() const;
        std::string toProperString() const; // properString format of 15/4   is  3 3/4

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Fraction const& rhs);
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Fraction& rhs);
};

#endif

// for the Fraction.cpp file:

#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>

int Fraction::getNum() const
{
    return numer;
}

int Fraction::getDen() const
{
    return denom;
}

static int gcd(int n, int d)      //moving sign to numerator
{
    if(n<0)
        n=-n;
    if(d<0)
        d=-d;
    if(n<d)
        return gcd(d,n);
    if(d==0)
        return n;
    return gcd(d,n%d);
}

Fraction::Fraction(int numerator, int den) : numer(numerator), denom(den)
{
    assert(denom != 0);
    reduce();
}

void Fraction::reduce()
{
    int sign = 1;
    if (numer < 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        numer = -numer;
    }
    if (numer< 0)
    {
        sign = -1;
        denom = -denom;
    }
    assert(denom != 0);
    int d = 1;
    if (numer>0)
    {
        d     = gcd(numer, denom);
        numer = sign*(numer / d);
        denom = denom / d;
    }
}

Fraction::Fraction(std::string const& s)
    : Fraction()
{
    std::istringstream iss(s);

    char delimiter = 0;

    if (
            (iss >> numer)
         && (iss >> delimiter)
         && (delimiter == '/')
         && (iss >> denom))
    {
        assert(denom != 0);
        reduce();
    } else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("invalid conversion to Fraction");
    }
}

Fraction::Fraction(Fraction const& other)
    : numer(other.numer), denom(other.denom)
{
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator=(Fraction const& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        numer = rhs.numer;
        denom = rhs.denom;
    }
    return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator+ (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return Fraction(numer*rhs.denom + denom*rhs.numer, denom*rhs.denom);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator- (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return Fraction(numer*rhs.denom - denom*rhs.numer, denom*rhs.denom);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator*(Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return Fraction(numer*rhs.numer, denom*rhs.denom);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator/(Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return Fraction(numer*rhs.denom, denom*rhs.numer);
}

bool Fraction::operator > (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return static_cast<double>(*this) > rhs;
}

bool Fraction::operator >= (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return (*this == rhs) || static_cast<double>(*this) > rhs;
}

bool Fraction::operator == (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return (1l*numer*rhs.denom == 1l*denom*rhs.numer);
}

bool Fraction::operator < (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return static_cast<double>(*this) < rhs;
}

bool Fraction::operator <= (Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return (*this == rhs) || static_cast<double>(*this) < rhs;
}

bool Fraction::operator!=(Fraction const& rhs) const
{
    return !(*this == rhs);
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator++()  //prefix
{
    numer += denom;
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator++(int) //postfix
{
    Fraction temp = *this;
    numer += denom;
    reduce();
    return temp;
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator--()
{
    numer -= denom;
    reduce();
    return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator--(int)
{
    Fraction temp = *this;
    numer -= denom;
    reduce();
    return temp;
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator+=(Fraction const& rhs)
{
    return *this = (*this + rhs);
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator-=(Fraction const& rhs)
{
    return *this = (*this - rhs);
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator*=(Fraction const& rhs)
{
    return *this = (*this * rhs);
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator/=(Fraction const& rhs)
{
    return *this = (*this / rhs);
}

// utility
template <typename T>
T int_pow(T x, unsigned exponent)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>(), "only supports integral types");

    intmax_t base = x, result = 1;

    while (exponent != 0)
    {
        // TODO protect against overflows
        if (exponent % 2)
            result *= base;

        exponent /= 2;
        base *= base;
    }

    assert(result <= std::numeric_limits<T>::max()); // value too large to be represented
    assert(result >= std::numeric_limits<T>::min()); // value too small to be represented
    return static_cast<T>(result);
}

Fraction Fraction::operator^(unsigned n) const
{
    return Fraction(int_pow(numer, n), int_pow(denom, n));
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator^=(unsigned n)
{
    return *this = (*this ^ n);
}

bool Fraction::isZero() const
{
    return numer == 0;
}

bool Fraction::isProper() const
{
    return abs(numer)<abs(denom);
}

bool Fraction::isNegative() const
{
    return numer<0;
}

bool Fraction::isPositive() const
{
    return numer>0;
}

Fraction::operator std::string() const
{
    return toString();
}

Fraction::operator double() const
{
    return (static_cast<double>(numer) / denom);
}

std::string Fraction::toString() const
{
    return std::to_string(numer) + '/' + std::to_string(denom);
}

std::string Fraction::toProperString() const
{
    int a   = numer / denom;
    int num = numer % denom;

    std::ostringstream ostr;
    ostr << a << " " << Fraction(num, denom);
    return ostr.str();
}

std::ostream& operator <<  (std::ostream& out, Fraction const& rhs)
{
    if(rhs.denom!=1)
        return out << rhs.getNum() << "/" << rhs.denom;
    else
        return out << rhs.getNum();
}

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& in, Fraction& rhs)
{
    int n, d = 1;
    char c;

    if (in >> n >> c)
    {
        if (c == '/')
        {
            in >> d;
        }
        else
        {
            in.putback(c);
        }
        rhs = Fraction(n, d);
    }
    return in;
}

// And here's the main program

int main()
{
    Fraction a1;
    Fraction a(1,2);
    Fraction b(4,5);
    Fraction c(6,8);
    Fraction d(b);
    Fraction g(-4,8);
    Fraction g1(4,-10);
    Fraction z(7,5);

    std::cout << "a1: " << a1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "a : " << a  << "\n";
    std::cout << "b : " << b  << "\n";
    std::cout << "c : " << c  << "\n";
    std::cout << "d : " << d  << "\n";
    std::cout << "g : " << g  << "\n";
    std::cout << "g1: " << g1 << "\n";

    std::string s  = "3/4";
    std::string s1 = "2/-3";
    Fraction b1(s);
    Fraction b2(s1);

    std::cout << "b1: " << b1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "b2: " << b2 << "\n";

    a1 = b + c; std::cout << "a1 = b + c; // " << a1 << "\n";
    a1 = b-c  ; std::cout << "a1 = b-c  ; // " << a1 << "\n";
    a1 = b*c  ; std::cout << "a1 = b*c  ; // " << a1 << "\n";
    a1 = b / c; std::cout << "a1 = b / c; // " << a1 << "\n";

    b += a;     std::cout << "b += a; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b -= a;     std::cout << "b -= a; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b /= a;     std::cout << "b /= a; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b++   ;     std::cout << "b++   ; // "     << b  << "\n";
    ++b   ;     std::cout << "++b   ; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b--   ;     std::cout << "b--   ; // "     << b  << "\n";
    --b   ;     std::cout << "--b   ; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b /= a;     std::cout << "b /= a; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b *= a;     std::cout << "b *= a; // "     << b  << "\n";
    b ^= 2u;    std::cout << "b ^= 2; // "     << b  << "\n";

    std::cout << a.toString()       << "\n";
    std::cout << z.toProperString() << "\n";

    Fraction f1(-4,5);
    Fraction f2(0,1);
    std::cout << "is f1 negative? "            << std::boolalpha << f1.isNegative() << "\n";
    std::cout << "is f2 zero? "                << std::boolalpha << f2.isZero()     << "\n";
    std::cout << "is f1 a proper fraction? "   << std::boolalpha << f1.isProper()   << "\n";
    std::cout << "is f1 a positive fraction? " << std::boolalpha << f1.isPositive() << "\n";

    a = Fraction(9, 8);
    b = Fraction(7, 8);

    if (a < b)
        std::cout << "a is smaller than b"     << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "a is not smaller than b" << "\n";

    if(a==b)
        std::cout << "a is equal to b"         << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "a is not equal to b"     << "\n";
}
```

Comment: itoa works for visual studio 2010 but not 2013, thanks for your tips

Comment: I know. That's why I mentioned standards. I'll be reviewing the rest, and posting a fixed version :)

Comment: There. I finally reached a point where I considered the review "done" for now. See the edit (starting from ***time passes***). See the resulting code **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca2442bf5b064812)**

Comment: Wow! Definitely a +1 for effort.